# Deploy of EJB 3.0 MDB with Spring tells me that my component is already defined

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0

I'm getting the following exception on the deploy from eclipse telling me that I've got a duplicate component. It's only defined as one class that I can see. I've tried renaming it in case it interferes with an existing component in JBoss (saw someone with this problem) with the same results. It's the first time I've used  @Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class). Have I got it configured wrong? I've used Eclipse/Kepler to create as an EJB 3.0 project and then to Configure/Convert to a Maven project. I wondered if this had caused two identical classes to be generated but using a linux find command tells me there's just one MdbDequeueFrom.class. The project will deploy and execute in the debugger ok if I comment out:

```
//    @Stateless
//    @Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
```

except the beans don't get injected.

Exception when they are not commented out:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011046: A component named 
           'MdbDequeueFrom' is already defined in this module
    at 
   org.jboss.as.ee.component.EEModuleDescription.addComponent(EEModuleDescription.java:140)
```

My MDB is defined as:

```
   @MessageDriven(
    activationConfig = { @ActivationConfigProperty(
            propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue =   
                       "javax.jms.Queue"), 
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination",  
     propertyValue = "java:jboss/activemq/queue/IN_FROM"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="acknowledgeMode", 
      propertyValue="Auto-acknowledge")
    })
   @Stateless
   @Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
   @ResourceAdapter("activemq-ra.rar")
   public class MdbDequeueFrom implements MessageListener {

   @Autowired
   private ReferralService referralService;

   public MdbDequeueFrom() {

   }
```

with the service defined as:

```
   @Service("referralService")
   @Transactional(readOnly = false)
   public class ReferralServiceImpl implements ReferralService {

   private static final Logger logger = 
     LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReferralServiceImpl.class);

   @Autowired
   private ReferralDao referralDao;
```

my beanRefContext.xml is :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <beans>
       <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
       <constructor-arg value="classpath*:applicationContext.xml" />
     </bean>
   </beans>
```

my application.context has:

```
      <context:component-scan base-package="com.MdbDequeue"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
     <property name="jndiName" value="java:/OracleDS"/>
     </bean>

   <bean id="sessionFactory" 
     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:hbm/Referral.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
        </props>

    </property>
   </bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" 
     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" 
     class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
      p:basenames="messages" />

<context:annotation-config />

</beans>
```

it's defined as an EJB 3.0 Maven project with

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org  /2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
   <artifactId>MdbDequeuer</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>ejb</packaging>
   <name>MdbDequeuer</name>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue occurs, there is a duplicate bean included by one of jar library under WEB-INF/lib/.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor, you must be very careful as to not have that bean scanned by spring context scanners, as that will lead to trouble. The manual [warns about this as well](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ejb/interceptor/SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.html):

> WARNING: Do not define the same bean as Spring-managed bean and as
>   EJB3 session bean in the same deployment unit. In particular, be
>   careful when using the  feature in combination
>   with the deployment of Spring-based EJB3 session beans: Make sure that
>   the EJB3 session beans are not autodetected as Spring-managed beans as
>   well, using appropriate package restrictions.

I think you should remove this:

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

and confirm that this doesn't cover your MDB:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.MdbDequeue"/>
```

So you should use component-scan only on packages *other than* the one you have the bean in. Annotation-config is not needed if you use component-scan on all relevant packages. Component-scan does a superset of what annotation-config does.

Comment: That seems like a likely culprit but I tried removing both and I still get the duplicate component error. I also moved services, dao etc to a separate package and left in, with changes, the base-package scan and also still got the error.

Comment: @user1069528 have you restarted the server? without it, old configurations stay in memory

Comment: @user1069528 do a search of string 'MdbDequeueFrom' throughout all your files (including all xml!) and let us know of the results

Comment: I'm having what looks like a secondary problem with JBoss not automatically deploying with the default standalone.xml or  auto-deploy-zipped="true" auto-deploy-exploded="false" set. Hard to see how these are related. It will deploy and then generate the duplicate error if I create a xxx.jar.dodeploy. This wasn't happening with Stateless and  Interceptors commented out.

Comment: I've done that earlier. Did it again now. I just get the MdbDequeueFrom class and the MdbDequeueFrom constructor.

Comment: Driving home it occurred to me that maybe my applicationcontext.xml is not in the right place for this separation of the EJB and service and dao parts you mention. I will check tomorrow. I haven't been able to find a good example of how to set up this separation.

Comment: I think my code is ok at least now. I'm thinking this is a JBoss bug since I see other people have had this error without resolution. I'm going to try another app server.

Comment: @user1069528 it would be peculiar if it were a bug as we use MDBs with spring in jboss as7 all the time, and we've never encountered such bug.

Comment: Hard to tell where there might be a problem. I converted to Spring MPB removing the EJB 3 and now works fine. Thanks for your help,